# Prolog Lists with Lists inside

Tags: prolog

I'm a total newbie in Prolog I have this code (I'm sorry if its not very friendly to read)

```
AdjOfAll(State,[FreeSpace],[Result]):-
     Adj(State,FreeSpace,Result).
AdjOfAll(State,[Space|NextSpace],[X|Xs]):-
     AdjOfAll(State,NextSpace,Xs),
     Adj(State,Space,X).
```

my problem is that Adj returns `[ (element_1), ... , (element_n) ]`

My objective with AdjOfAll was to get,

```
[ ( element_1), ..., (element_n), (element_1_from 2nd adj), ... ]
```

but i get

```
[ [ ( element_1), ... ,(element_n)] , [ (element_1_from 2nd adj) ], ... ]
```

I hope its understandable what I'm trying to say, sorry for the bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see if [flatten](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=flatten/2)/2 can help you to get the right output. Place it after the top level call to AdjOfAll/3.

```
...
AdjOfAll(State, NextSpace, ResultNested),
flatten(ResultNested, Result),
...
```

BTW are you sure your predicates are named correctly? Usually they are *lowercase*.

Comment: thank you flatten works. by the way it was my bad translating to be easier to read but yes in the original is adjOfAll :)